# Sharepoint 2013 workflow to update list item and trigger another workflow to start on second list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I have searched and searched and have not found anything that is comparable to my situation, so if there is already an answer I apologize upfront.

I have a calendar list (list a) with a custom content type, on this list users enter information.  Upon entering this information, the workflow is initiated which then, depending on the user, updates information in another list (list b) which is on a static row.  Once the list b item has been updated, there is supposed to be a workflow that is started to update information in list c and list d.

I have this working on a subsite that I created back in 2015, all of the same basic steps, all SP2013 workflows.  I can create a new list item that meets the criteria for initiating the workflow and it will flow through the lists as its supposed to.  My problem is on the new subsite that I have created, I cannot get it to perform the same function.

So basically I have two sites where one will allow a SP2013 workflow to initiate a SP2013 workflow on a separate list and one that will not allow that.  I have also created a SP2010 workflow on the list that will not allow it and it does perform as described on the original subsite.  My only problem with this is I have (1) two days until I have to demonstrate this as working and (2) its working on one and not the other, how is this possible?  I can test whatever needs to be tested.

Comment: Is this a different farm? Did you try to copy the workflows over to a new instead of recreating it? Are you using the web service action to initiate the work flow?

Answer (score 0):

Take you Reusable WF or List WF in WF 4.0 or WF 3.0? Give more Information about Structure in SiteCol and Deploying WFs inside there. Give more Information about exceptions, error or behavior in Lists, where you bind the WFs.

Comment: Not sure about the WF 4.0 or 3.0.  It is a list workflow, not reusable.  I create workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013, then just publish the workflow to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to cover the call in an app step, see http://info.summit7systems.com/blog/app-step-or-impersonation-step-in-sharepoint-designer-2013
There is an active workflow recursion prevention, see
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2014/08/21/fix-sharepoint-2013-workflow-recursion-prevention-part-2/